# Hive change column name without knowing column data type

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to change the column name of a Hive table without changing it's datatype.

I tried below query but it requires datatype which I don't know.

```
ALTER TABLE test CHANGE a a1 INT;
```

I would like to prefix `SALES_` before all my columns irrespective of their column types.

**Input Table**

`emp_id(int) emp_name(string) salary(double)`

**Output Table**

`sales_emp_id(int) sales_emp_name(string) sales_salary(double)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain which is the scenario you would need this operation for?

Answer (score 1):

Well, altering the column name in hive using `alter table command` require its datatype.
For this purpose you may perform the below commands,

1)Create a new  table with the your new column names)

```
create table newTable (sales_emp_id int ,sales_emp_name string, sales_salary double) ;
```

2)Insert into new table from old table

```
insert into newTable select * from oldtable;
```

3)Now,you may drop your old table.

```
  drop table oldtable;
```

The above code may be used if creating a new table sounds ok for you.

Well if you use a shell script , something like below:

```
    while read line;do
    SOURCE_TABLENAME= `echo $line| awk -F" " '{print $1}'`
    TARGET_TABLENAME= `echo $line| awk -F" " '{print $2}'`
    LOC=`echo "$line"| awk -F" " '{print $3}'`
    PREFIX="emp_"
    S=`hive -e "desc $SOURCE_TABLENAME"`

    VAL=echo $S |sed 's/\(\(\w\w*\W*\)\{2\}\)/\1\n/g' | sed 's/$/,/g' | sed -e 's/^/$PREFIX/'

    STATEMENT="CREATE TABLE $SOURCE_TABLENAME (`echo $VAL) as select * from $SOURCE_TABLENAME LOCATION $LOC`"
hive -e "drop table $SOURCE_TABLENAME"
    done <   INPUT_FILE.txt
```

### INPUT_FILE.txt

source_table target_table location   (all inputs separated by space)

Comment: I just know the new column names in order but I don't know the datatype of the columns whether it is int, string or double.  So I can't create a new table without the datatypes.

Comment: can you see the old table and then recreate it?or you can print the schema of the old table in a file

Comment: I need to do this for lot of tables I can't do this manually for all the tables.I want this to be done programmatically. so if there is an approach to achieve this without manual intervention, I can write a shell script for all the other tables.

Comment: seems like shells script is the only option right now. Answer editied

Answer (score 0):

Without creating new table, you can use the REPLACE function in hive to change all the column names. The command looks like this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name REPLACE COLUMNS (sales_emp_id INT,sales_emp_name STRING,sales_salary DOUBLE);
```

Now you can use the describe command to check the column names

```
describe table_name;
```

Comment: Depending on the data types you can change again using the same replace function

Comment: Ofcourse you are right. But I want this to be done programmatically. so I can't do this manually for all the tables

Comment: @Munesh - so are you looking for shell script like solution that can prefix all tables' columns' with `sales_` in given hive database?

Comment: Yes. I can write a shell script but I need an approach to achieve that. I dont know why we need datatype while changing column name in hive